# How do I echo the words "on" and "off" in the command line?

Tags: cmd, echo, prompt

If I run the command prompt and type in the command:

```
echo on
echo off
```

It will not display any output.
If I type in:

```
echo a
```

The output will be the character

```
a
```

Is there any way I can make the command prompt output the words

```
on
off
```

through an echo command?

Comment: echo "on"  or echo "off"

Comment: @GaurabDahal that simply produces the characters
`"on"` and `"off"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo.on
echo.off
```

worked on Windows 7.